# ssh asks for passphrase at each git push

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket account set with ssh key 
I have copied the ssh public and private keys in my .ssh folder 
I have added a ssh config file :

```
cat .ssh/config 

host bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket-ssh-key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

The ssh identification works well BUT it asks for my passphrase at each git push .. witch goes again the purpuse of all this setting.
What have I done wrong ?

Comment: Did you give the ssh key a passphrase when you made it?

Comment: Yes, the issue is I need to give it again and again for each push...

Comment: I don’t give a passphrase to my ssh key. It’s probably bad practice.

Comment: Bad practice to give one or not to ? (Sorry not sure what you intend to say)

Comment: (I didn't, as it then doesn't ask me every time I push/pull)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not have your private key added to the agent.

See if doing an `ssh-add ~/.ssh/<private key file>` helps.

Also, make sure the agent is running.

Check here: https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.12/user/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Answer (score 0):

I get an error :

```
ssh-add .ssh/bitbucket-ssh-key
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

I had forgotten to start the ssh-agent

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Then git push went without a glitch ;)

Thanks for the RTFM pointer!